# error with \t in last step of while loop (c++)

Tags: c++, indentation

I'm trying to perfect an `aligned multiplication table`. All is good, but the `\t` kinda falters in the very last step of the loop. It inserts double the space intended only in this step and I don't know why.

```
int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    int i = 1;
    while (i<=N)
    {
        int j = 1;
        while (j<=N)
        {
            cout << "(" << i << "x";
            cout << j << ")";
            cout << "=" << i*j;
            j++;
            cout << "\t\t";
        }

        i++;
        cout << "\n";
    }
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

The output: 
[image: output]

Comment: How much space do you expect, and how much space do you get? Does the error occur when N=1?

Comment: Include `<iomanip>` and use [`setw()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw). Try `setw(10)` as the first output to `cout` in the `while` loop.

Comment: Hint: replace `cout << "=" << i*j;` with `cout << "=" << 0;` and observe what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to solve your problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int N;
   cin >> N;
   int i = 1;
   while (i<=N)
   {
       int j = 1;
       while (j<=N)
       {
           cout << "(" << i << "x" << j << ")" << "=" << i*j;
           if (i*j < 10) cout << "\t\t";
           else cout << "\t";
           j++;
       }

       i++;
       cout << endl;
   }
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Your problem doesn't only occur in the last iteration. It occurs after the first 2-digit result (eg. try running your code for N = 5). Because of the existence of one more digit in the result (in your example because of (4x3)=12) the following operation to be printed in that line is pushed one \t to the right.